# Change liquid variable on click

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I want to change the DOM on click. Here is my Liquid (google.md):

```
---
layout: pastTournaments
title: Google Tournament
permalink: /tournaments/google/
---

<h5 class="column-wrapper centered">These are the rankings for the Google Qualifying tournament, which was hosted on December 2, 2017.</h5>
<br>
<div class="column-wrapper">
    <div class="grid-x">
        <div class="large-6 shrink cell">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th width="20" class="centered">Rank</th>
                    <th width="150" class="centered">Team Number</th>
                    <th width="150" class="centered">Team</th>
                    <th width="50" class="centered">QP</th>
                    <th width="50" class="centered">RP</th>
                    <th width="50" class="centered">Plays</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% assign sorted = site.data.google.teams | sort:"rank" %}
                    {% for team in sorted %}
                        <tr class="table" onclick="ranks()">
                            <td class="centered">{{ team.rank }}</td>
                            <td class="centered">{{ team.number }}</td>
                            <td class="centered">{{ team.name }}</td>
                            <td class="centered">{{ team.qp }}</td>
                            <td class="centered">{{ team.rp }}</td>
                            <td class="centered">{{ team.plays }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor%}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        {% for team in site.data.google.teams %}
        <!--I want to remove this if tag because it is specific to one team-->
            {% if team.name == 'Q' %}
                <!--I want to move this line -->
                <div class="large-6 shrink cell">
                    <h2 class="centered"><strong>{{ team.number }} {{ team.name }}</strong></h2>
                    <h4 class="centered"><strong>Rank: </strong>#{{ team.rank }}</h4>
                    <p class="centered"><strong>QP: </strong>{{ team.qp }}</p>
                    <p class="centered"><strong>RP: </strong>{{ team.rp }}</p>
                    <p class="centered"><strong>Plays: </strong>{{ team.plays }}</p>
                    <div id="ranks-right"></div>
                <!--To this line -->
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

    </div>
</div>
```

I need it so that the {{ team.name }} will be set to the team that is clicked.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to print the same datas twice.

Comment: i dont, i want to move it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to set a Jekyll variable on a click. This is not possible. You are not fully understanding the way Jekyll works. You are almost there... but the thing you are missing is that variables are only set during build. If you want something in the DOM to change on a click, you will have to use javascript. Liquid is not able to help you with that. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, But do you know how to do that?

Comment: I am willing to help you with that. But please try it yourself first and ask a new question to describe the problems you run into.